# Getting the values of the dropdownlists in loop table rows in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm  creating a grid table where in users can add an application or delete an application they need. Application that are for resetting needs to choose if resetting is (sign on, override or sign on and override) from the dropdown, aside from resetting type, the user should input a userid too.

My problem is that, the rows of my grid is loop, so my dropdown has one id and one class and the same for the textbox for my userid. I can save the entered text in the userid textbox using document.getElementsByName. However, I cannot get all the selected values in my dropdowns, I only get the value of the dropdown in the first row.

[image: image of the grid table]

Here is my code for the dropdownList:

```
public string GetResettingList()
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();



    try
    {
        //select action
        html.Append("<table style=\"width:24% !important;\">");
        html.Append("<tr>");
        html.Append("<td style=\"text-align:left;\"><select id=\"ddlreset\" style=\"width:150px;\" onchange=\"\"><option value=\"\">--Please Select--</option>");

        var sAction = _DataEntryBLL.showResettingList();
        foreach (var r in sAction)
        {
            html.Append("<option value=\"" + r.resetCode + "\">" + r.resetDesc.ToString() + "</option>");
        }
        html.Append("</table>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        html.Clear();
        html.Append("Error found." + ex.Message);
    }

    return html.ToString();
}
```

Here is my code in ASP.NET:

```
try
{
    ShowList = _DataEntryBLL.showBranchSingleRequest(position);
    if (ShowList.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var app in ShowList)
        {
            //content = "content=\"" + app.ApplicationID + ";" + app.ApplicationDesc + ";" + app.Applicationshortname + "\"";
            html.Append("<tr>");
            if (prevAppId != app.applicationid)
            {
                html.Append("<td width=\"5%\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"chkapp\" class=\"check-app\" id = \"chkapp" + app.applicationid + "\"  value=\"" + app.applicationid + "\">");
                html.Append("<td colspan=\"1\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\"><b>" + app.applicationDesc.ToString() + "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdnbranchappid\" value=\"" + app.applicationid + "\"></td>");
                //html.Append("<td ></td><td ></td>");
                html.Append("<td  id=\"tdDdlreset\" class=\"reset-type\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\">" + GetResettingList() + "<input type=\"text\" id=\"hdnDdlresetvalue\"></td>");
                html.Append("<td width=\"40%\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"UserAppID\"><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdnbranchprofid\" value=\"" + app.profileID + "\"></td></tr>");
            }
            html.Append("<tr><td ></td> <td ></td><td ></td>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
            prevAppId = app.applicationid;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        html.Append("<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\"> No Records found.</td>");
        html.Append("</tr>");
    }
    html.Append("</table>");
    html.Append("<div  style=\"padding-top:1%;\"><input type=\"button\"    class=\"btnDeleteApplication\" value=\"Delete Application/s \"> <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"\"></div>");
    html.Append("</div>");
}
```

Here is my code in JS

```
function SaveResettingBranchRequest() {
    var input = "";
    var branchuserid = document.getElementsByName("UserAppID");
    var branchApp = document.getElementsByName("hdnbranchappid");

   //dropdown reset
   var resetType = document.getElementById("ddlreset");
   var reset = resetType.options[resetType.selectedIndex].value;

    for (var i = 1; i < branchApp.length; i++) {
        input += branchApp[i].value + ":" + branchuserid[i].value + ":" +reset[i].value + "|";
    }
    //Call ajax here...
}
```

If I select a 3 application of:

- network with resetting type of sign on from dropdown and userid P123405
- as400  with resetting type of override from dropdown and userid 22089
- Stock  with resetting type of sign on and override from dropdown and  userid 203412

I should get the following:

```
network | sign on              | P123405
as400   | override             | 22089
Stock   | sign on and override | 203412
```

but all I get is the value of the **first row which is the network application**.

Please Help I tried everything I found in the net but it only gets the first row.

Edited.-- I forgot the dropdown id.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi I updated the format of your question. Make sure to indent code with at least 4 spaces, and to separate such block with empty lines from the running text, so it gets formatted correctly. Please add the code of `GetResettingList`, as that is where I suppose you generate the drop down lists. Also add the code that defines the `reset` array in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for updating my question. :)))))

Answer (score 0):

Some issues that need correction:

- The first `td` tag (with the check box) is not closed;
- The `b` tag in the second `td` is not closed;
- The loop generates several elements with the same *id* attribute value (also for the drop-down); this is not allowed in HTML -- change to *name* attributes, for which duplicates are allowed;
- Twice you use *getElementsByName* (good!), but pass an *id* value as argument, not a name. But if you fix the previous point, and change the HTML *id* attributes to *name* attributes, this code should work;
- For retrieving the `select` elements, you should also use *getElementsByName*, which should work once you have done the above changes;
- to retrieve the selected value of a `select` element, you can just use its value property; you don't need to go to the *options* collection;
- that selected value should be retrieved inside the loop, so you can differentiate between the different `select` elements;
- The JavaScript loop starts with index 1, but it should start at 0.

Here are lines of HTML producing lines, which should get a *name* attribute instead of *id*; the first one is from *GetRessetingList*:

```
html.Append("<td style=\"text-align:left;\"><select id=\"ddlreset\" style=\"width:150px;\" onchange=\"\"><option value=\"\">--Please Select--</option>");


html.Append("<td width=\"5%\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"chkapp\" class=\"check-app\" id = \"chkapp" + app.applicationid + "\"  value=\"" + app.applicationid + "\">");
html.Append("<td colspan=\"1\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\"><b>" + app.applicationDesc.ToString() + "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdnbranchappid\" value=\"" + app.applicationid + "\"></td>");
//html.Append("<td ></td><td ></td>");
html.Append("<td  id=\"tdDdlreset\" class=\"reset-type\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\">" + GetResettingList() + "<input type=\"text\" id=\"hdnDdlresetvalue\"></td>");
html.Append("<td width=\"40%\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"UserAppID\"><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdnbranchprofid\" value=\"" + app.profileID + "\"></td></tr>");
```

Some *id* attribute values are OK, because they have the application Id included, but change the rest as follows:

```
html.Append("<td style=\"text-align:left;\"><select name=\"ddlresetName\" style=\"width:150px;\" onchange=\"\"><option value=\"\">--Please Select--</option>");

html.Append("<td width=\"5%\">" +
    "<input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"chkapp\" class=\"check-app\"" +
    "id = \"chkapp" + app.applicationid + "\"  value=\"" +
    app.applicationid + "\">");
html.Append("<td colspan=\"1\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\"><b>" +
    app.applicationDesc.ToString() + "</b>" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hdnbranchappName\" value=\"" + 
    app.applicationid + "\"></td>");
//html.Append("<td ></td><td ></td>");
html.Append("<td  name=\"tdDdlreset\" class=\"reset-type\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\">" +
    GetResettingList() +
    "<input type=\"text\" name=\"hdnDdlresetvalueName\"></td>");
html.Append("<td width=\"40%\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color:#EEE\">" + 
    "<input type=\"text\" name=\"UserAppName\">" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hdnbranchprofName\" value=\"" +
    app.profileID + "\"></td></tr>");
```

Once those changes have been made, this JavaScript code should give better results:

```
function SaveResettingBranchRequest() {
    var input = "";
    var branchuserid = document.getElementsByName("UserAppName");
    var branchApp = document.getElementsByName("hdnbranchappName");
    //dropdown reset
    var resetType = document.getElementByName("ddlresetName");

    for (var i = 0; i < branchApp.length; i++) {
        input += branchApp[i].value + ":" + 
                 branchuserid[i].value + ":" +
                 resetType[i].value + "|";
    }
    //Call ajax here...
}
```

#### Remarks

The code as you have provided it originally would find *branchApp.length* to be 0 (as there are no elements with the matching name), and so it would not produce anything. I guess you broke the code further by trying to simplify it for the question.

As you'll have to change several *id* attributes to *name* attributes, some other code might break. So you should check any dependencies on these *id* attributes and change the code accordingly. *id* attributes are only useful if you have JavaScript that addresses those elements via their *id*. In the code you provided there is no such need.